# Python: Converting degrees to radians - Not working

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have tried doing the following in Python with numpy but my answer is not coming out to the value I want. I want `cos(30) = 0.866`

```
import math
import numpy as np

print(math.degrees(np.cos(30)))
print(np.cos(math.degrees(30)))
print(math.degrees(math.cos(30)))
print(math.cos(math.degrees(30)))
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: `print(np.cos(math.radians(30)))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

python math.cos expects angle in radian. so you first have to change degrees to radians.

```
radian = math.radians(30)
print(math.cos(radian))
# 0.866025403784
```

Answer (score 3):

`math.degrees` converts radians to degrees but you are obviously giving it degrees, you want to use `math.radians` to convert degrees to radians

```
print(np.cos(math.radians(30))
```

Answer (score 0):

Only using `math` module

```
import math
print(math.cos(math.radians(30)))

>>0.8660254037844387
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from math import cos, radians
print(cos(radians(30)))
```

Output:

```
0.8660254037844387
```

Answer (score -1):

**Manual approach:**

```
import math


def to_radian(degree):
    return degree * math.pi/180

print(math.cos(to_radian(30)))


Out[0]: 0.866025403784
```