# Questions about the function of Sine, Cosine, and Tangent in Python

Tags: python, math, module, trigonometry

I am starting to learn the math module in Python and I am trying to wrap my head around the trigonometry functions of sine, cosine, and tangent in Python.

I spent some time learning more about trigonometry and understand how the basic formulas work for right angled triangles:

Sine Function:
sin(θ) equals Opposite / Hypotenuse

Cosine Function:
cos(θ) equals Adjacent / Hypotenuse

Tangent Function:
tan(θ) equals Opposite / Adjacent

But I am not clear on how this applies in Python when it only accepts one value. I read that the value must be a radian.

So if x = 1 radian and math.sin(x)

Output equals 0.8414709848078965

So the sine of 1 radian is 0.8414709848078965

So my question is what did the sine function actually do to a radian of 1?

I am hoping the answer will also help me understand what is happening if I did cosine and tangent to radian 1.

Comment: "*the sine of 1 radian is 0.84...*" This means that if you draw any right triangle with an angle of 1 radian (= 180/π ≈ 57.3 degrees), the ratio between the side opposite that angle and the hypotenuse will be ≈ 0.84.

Comment: The python trig functions like [`sin(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sin) expect input angular values to be in units of [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian).  If you are more used to working in degrees see e.g. [Python: Converting degrees to radians - Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48900310/3744182) and [How can I convert radians to degrees with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9875964/3744182).

Answer (score 2):

python is using the taylor series of sin to find the value of sin 1.
https://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf

Also, when you said how this is true when it accepts one value. I think you have a misconception. The sin, cosine, tangent functions take one argument i.e. theta and outputs a single value.
Now, that value is equal to the base/hypotenuse (*or whichever the trig function you have used*) of the triangle of which angle you input in the trig function. SO you must not expect trig functions to give out two values.